# If gravity can catch up a light photon (speed=$c$) and change its wavelength is it faster than light?

Tags: gravity, photons, gravitational-waves, causality, faster-than-light

Why can gravity catch up a light photon (speed=$c$) and change its wavelength? How can that be logic although nature shows somehow it is... Maybe gravity has different speed than gravitational waves and that's why it can reach the photon?

Comment: Why does gravity have to 'catch up' to a photon?

Comment: How do you define the speed of gravity?

Answer (score 2):

The gravity you're talking about is a *static* gravitational field, whose state has *already* propagated far past the photon that it affects. Thus, gravity doesn't have to catch up with the photon. In fact, speed of gravity is irrelevant here.